# Solve the algorithmic problem with an end recursive form

Tags: haskell, recursion

Input: List xs with arbitrary numeric elements, xs has at least two elements / Output: smallest distance between adjacent elements in the list.

-- Input: List xs with at least two numeric elements & its implementation an end recursive function.
-- Erg: Returns the smallest distance of adjacent elements from the output list.

```
minimumdistance :: [Int] -> Int
minimumdistance [] = error "Empty list".
minimumdistance [_] = error "Requirement is not met".
minimumdistance [a,b] = abs (a - b)
minimaldistance (x:y:xs) = helper (abs (x - y)) xs where 
   helper :: Int -> [Int] -> Int 
   helper acc [] = acc
   helper acc (z:zs) = if (abs (y - z)) < acc then helper (abs (y - z)) zs else helper 
   acc zs
```

Is the function endrecursive because that we are supposed to solve the task endrecursive and I am sure because I do not have the definition yet correctly, but I also on other pages, the endrecursive representation not understood

Comment: I have not encountered "end-recursive" before. Is this the same as "tail-recursive"?

Comment: Our definition is: A recursive call is simply called if it directly returns the value of the calling function (see foldl)
-- => recursion call corresponds to outer function
-- A function is final recursive, if all function calls are plain (see foldl)

Comment: It sounds as though you are describing tail recursion. The function you've shown would appear to be tail-recursive. Whether it's _right_, I cannot say.

Comment: The bigger problem is that your function doesn't work.  First, it has several syntax errors (periods at the end of statements).  Second, you've used both `minimumdistance` and `minimaldistance`, so you're actually defining two unrelated functions.  Third, even with these errors fixed, your function gives the wrong answer for the input `[10,20,30,31]`.  It gives `10` instead of the correct answer `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several issues mentioned in comments.

I suggest you break this down into smaller problems. We can write a tail-recursive function to get *pairs* of adjacent numbers from the list.

```
pairs [] = error "Not long enough"
pairs [_] = error "Not long enough"
pairs lst = aux lst []
 where
  aux (a:b:c) acc = aux (b:c) ((a, b):acc)
  aux _ acc = acc
```

Now, if we test this:

```
ghci> pairs [1, 3, 6, 7, 10]
[(7,10),(6,7),(3,6),(1,3)]
```

We can use `map` to get the differences.

```
ghci> map (\(a, b) -> abs (a - b)) $ pairs [1, 3, 6, 7, 10]
[3,1,3,2]
```

Now we just need to reduce that down to the minimum.

```
ghci> foldl1 min $ map (\(a, b) -> abs (a - b)) $ pairs [1, 3, 6, 7, 10]
1
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code for the `helper` function, the `y` variable does not get updated at all. Hence it remains equal to the second element of the *initial* input list in all successive scopes. This is probably not what you want.

It is more reliable to just include the *previous* list element into your state/accumulator, together with the smallest distance seen so far. This gives the following code:

```
minimumDistance :: [Int] -> Int
minimumDistance []       =  error "Empty list."
minimumDistance [_]      =  error "Requirement is not met."
minimumDistance (x:y:xs) =  helper  (abs (x-y), y)  xs  where
        helper (mnd,u)  []     =  mnd
        helper (mnd,u) (z:zs)  =  let  d1 = abs (u-z)
                                  in   if (d1 < mnd)  then  helper (d1,  z)  zs
                                                      else  helper (mnd, z)  zs
```

**Sanity check:**

We can generate a small random list, and compare the result of our `minimumDistance` function with the one obtained by just combining a few suitable library functions. Like this:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.10.7: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
...
 λ> 
 λ> :load q75011741.hs
 [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( q75011741.hs, interpreted )
 Ok, one module loaded.
 λ> 
 λ> :type minimumDistance
 minimumDistance :: [Int] -> Int
 λ> 
 λ> import System.Random (randomRs, mkStdGen)
 λ> 
 λ> g0 = mkStdGen 42
 λ> 
 λ> xs = take 20 $ randomRs (0,500) g0
 λ> 
 λ> xs
 [48,151,95,271,208,466,401,23,139,95,500,306,187,389,398,297,248,94,348,91]
 λ> 
 λ> minimumDistance xs
 9
 λ> 
 λ>
 λ> zip xs (tail xs)
 [(48,151),(151,95),(95,271),(271,208),(208,466),(466,401),(401,23),(23,139),(139,95),(95,500),(500,306),(306,187),(187,389),(389,398),(398,297),(297,248),(248,94),(94,348),(348,91)]
 λ> 
 λ> map (\(a,b) -> abs(a-b)) $ zip xs (tail xs) 
 [103,56,176,63,258,65,378,116,44,405,194,119,202,9,101,49,154,254,257]
 λ> 
 λ> minimum $ map (\(a,b) -> abs(a-b)) $ zip xs (tail xs) 
 9
 λ>
```

So it looks OK.

**Side note:**

If for comparison purposes one also wants a solution based on a library-provided recursion scheme, the [`foldl'` library function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:foldl-39-) can be used. This gives the following code change:

```
minimumDistance (x:y:xs) =  fst $ foldl' sfn acc0 xs   where
    acc0 = (abs(x-y), y)
    sfn (mnd, pv) z = let d1 = abs (pv-z)   in  if (d1 < mnd)  then (d1,  z)
                                                               else (mnd, z)
```